# Not being able to get image from URL and insert it into Recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm working on a project where we receive a link to an image and we're supposed to use it as an "icon" to a specific recycler view Item. I'm trying to use Picasso to get this done but It's not working. I have verified that the link is working.

This is my onBindViewHolder, where I'm using Picasso:

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(final TrailViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Trail t = mTrails.get(position);
        holder.mTrailName.setText(t.getTrail_name());
        holder.mTrailDesc.setText(t.getTrail_description());
        //Get image
        Picasso.get().load(t.getImage_src())
                     .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
                     .into(holder.mTrailImage);


}
```

I used `placeholder()` to make sure that the code was working and was in fact adding the image to the recycler view item, which it does.
The `t.getImage_src()` method returns a string with the link to the required image.

These are the permissions I've included in my android manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Is there any step that I'm missing?

Comment: Without the exception or error message, the issue can be anything from - image downscaling, HTTP error. Share the log to know more and help you.

Comment: @Charan the problem is that I'm not getting any error message. It just places the placeholder there every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true) to enable debugging so as to troubleshoot the exact cause . If the log has something like Error 504 try using:

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in Application tag of your manifest.

Comment: I got the Error 504 but I already had the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" included. My colleague just tested the app in his pc and it worked fine. We're both using emulators, could it be a configuration issue?

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and rebuild again?

Comment: I have, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: what's your Picasso dependency version?